# Не находит класс (Uncaught Error: Class )

Tags: php, классы

Всем доброго дня, не могу понять почему не работает (((

есть папочки

```
 - install
 --core
 ---installTables.php
 --config
 indexInstall.php
```

---

файл indexInstall.php

```
use install\core\InstallTables;

spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {

$path = str_replace('\\', '/', $class_name.'.php');
echo $path; //ПИШЕТ install/core/InstallTables.php
if(file_exists($path)){
require $path;
}

});

$install = new InstallTables();
$install->run();
```

---

---

Файл installTables.php

```
namespace install\core;

class InstallTables {

public $tables; 



public function __construct(){
$this->tables = require 'install/config/tables.php'; //

foreach ($this->tables as $val) {
echo $val;
}
}

public function run(){
echo 'Тут я запускаюсь';
}
}
```

---

Пишет ошибку
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class
Uncaught Error: Class 'install\core\InstallTables' not found in

---

вообщем проблема была в том что при использовывнии namespace, путь выстриавался не правильный!!!

Comment: indexInstall.php лежит в папке инсталл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сергей, ты стараешься подключить файл которого не существует. Файл называется install/core/**i**nstallTables.php, а ты подключаешь install/core/**I**nstallTables.php.
Также используется проверка на существование файла (`file_exists`) и подключение, если файл существует, но не используется обработка ситуаций, когда файла нет:

```
if (file_exists($path)) {
    // файл найден, подключаем файл
    require $path;
} else {
    // иначе - не найден
    $message = sprintf('File "%s" not exists', $path);
    die($message);
}
```

Также, исправив эту проблему ты столкнешься с другой: `PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` потому что в `InstallTables` задаешь свойству `$this->tables` результат `require`. Во первых - [require](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.require.php) возвращает не содержимое файла, а `1` если файл подключен и не возвращает ничего и `false` и предупреждение - если не подключен. Скорее всего тебе нужно собрать список файлов в той папке конфигов и заинклюдить каждый в цикле, а потом собирать структуру твоего `$this->tables`. Думаю, будет полезным [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge.php).

Так же посоветую почитать о [include](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php), [require](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.require.php), и их отличии от `include_once` и `require_once`.
Потом о [composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) и [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/). Ну и конечно же [PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/), [PSR-1](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/).

Comment: И include и require это не функции, а конструкции языка, поэтому они ничего не возвращают. И если в файле `install/config/tables.php` есть конструкция `return`, то то, что она возвращает и будет присвоено переменной.

Comment: @u_mulder согласен по поводу, что это не функции a специальная языковая конструкция, исправлю (а я, оказывается, и не писал, что это функция). Но вроде таки возвращает `false` если файл не найден. И единицу, если подключаемый файл не возвращает ничего. Могу ошибаться =)

Comment: Вероятно, но тем не менее неизвестно что у топик-стартера в подключаемом файле, возможно там есть `return`.

Comment: `$ php -r "var_dump(@require 'header.php');"`
`Command line code:1:
int(1)`